# I can't execute Sql UpperCase with lowerCase

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I am trying execute my app the SpringBoot in Mysql ,AWS -> Aurora -> Mysql,

When I execute , I get error the ->

[image]

I can upload all the complete trace.

You can see how table "USUARIO.TABLE" the problem is that the name the table is in lowerCase, because this say that my table doesn't exist.

I generate .war with the name the tables in UpperCase...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TP_P****")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class P***{
```

My pom.xml ->

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Data REST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SWAGGER -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Application.properties->

```
server.port = ***
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://*****:3306/*****?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=****
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=***
```

Version Mysql from AWS -> 5.6.10

If I try do " `Select name from tp_p***` ; "In lowerCase, I get error in AWS-AURORA-Myqsl because the table in lowerCase doesn't exist, In UPPERCASE ,My query is OK, But I writed my code in Java in UpperCase ,but when I execute my app, I get error for lowerCase....

Thanks.

Comment: Read the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) regarding this.  The bottom line is that in general if your underlying OS is case sensitive, then MySQL table/column names will also follow suit.  This would be the case of most flavors of UNIX (excluding Mac OS), but not on Windows.

Comment: I execute the app in Unix.

Comment: If you are using hibernate5, then you have to set spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy parameter in your application.properties

Comment: @EduBw Then you should always treat tables/columns are being case sensitive.  Really, this is general good practice, but probably required if you want to use MySQL on Linux.

Comment: I used spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy, But I get error ->Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy cannot be cast to org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set following property in MySQL parameter group

`lower_case_table_names=1`

Comment: 'lower_case_table_names' is an unknown property

Comment: From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html): `This works only on file systems that are not case-sensitive!` ... this won't work for the OP's Linux, I believe.

Comment: I used spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy, But I get error ->Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy cannot be cast to org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution ->

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```